# TimeTCPClient and TimeUDPClient both timing out

Tags: java, tcp, udp, ntp, apache-commons-net

I need the time from a NTP server.

I tied this:

```
  TimeUDPClient client = new TimeUDPClient();
  try {
        client.open();
        client.setSoTimeout(10000);
        client.getTime(InetAddress.getByName(host));
        client.close();
  } catch (IOException exp) {
        System.out.println("NTP connection error");
        exp.printStackTrace();
        return;
  }
```

After a 10 Sekonds I get this exception:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
>       at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:143)
>       at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:812)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.time.TimeUDPClient.getTime(TimeUDPClient.java:84)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.time.TimeUDPClient.getTime(TimeUDPClient.java:98)
>       at de.modusoft.opt.viewer.TimeSyncThread.run(TimeSyncThread.java:34)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I also tried this:

```
    TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    try {
        client.connect(host);
        Date ntpDate = client.getDate();
        client.disconnect();
        System.out.println("ntpDate = " + ntpDate);
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        System.out.println("NTP connection error");
        exp.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

And got also a Timout exception.

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
>       at de.modusoft.opt.viewer.TimeSyncThread.run(TimeSyncThread.java:29)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

host is a String and a tried "0.de.pool.ntp.org", "ntp.xs4all.nl".

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can a 'normal' client make a successful request to either of those servers from the same network to rule out anything else.

Comment: Yes, now I got it to work with ```NTPUDPClient client = new NTPUDPClient()```, but the code above does still not work.

Comment: The TimeUDPClient and TimeTCPClient classes connect to a time service that implements the time protocol as described in RFC 868 listening on port 37 which is not the same as a NTP service on port 123. Use NTPUDPClient for the NTP service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the time from an NTP server, you need to use the NTP protocol. The `TimeUDPClient` and `TimeTCPClient` classes use the Time Protocol, not NTP.

Comment: I changed to **org.apache.commons.net.ntp.NTPUDPClient**.